# How to undo accidental unsubscribe

Tags: support, email, email-notification, subscription, unsubscribe

I accidentally clicked on the "unsubscribe from all Stack Overflow emails" link that's included at the end of the autogenerated stack overflow mails, but I would very much like to continue getting emails from Stack Overflow.

Is there any way to "undo" this?

Comment: Probably only you could do is subscribe again?

Comment: @YOU: hmmmmmmmm

Comment: Out of curiosity since I've never done this: on the page the link took you to, was there a final confirmation before unsubscribing? (I'm assuming there wasn't.)

Comment: Would be nice if there was a confirmation page that listed all the newsletters this would cancel (ie, all active subscriptions) so one could verify that they aren't unsubscribing something they actually want to get, when they are merely trying to stop one particular newsletter.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You can only subscribe again.